# Global Variable Gives SIGSEGV

Tags: go, segmentation-fault, mutex, fibers

I am using Fiber to develop a backend.
I have a map that is a global variable that holds the socket connections.
When I use the global variable from the same package, no problem here, everything works fine. But, when I try to use the sockets from a route function, I am getting the error below.

I tried to use mutex.lock but no luck.

I checked the code, the socket is not nil in my sendToAll method but it becomes nil in the helper method( inside the lib: github.com/fasthttp/websocket.(*Conn).WriteMessage )

Any advice is welcome.

Thanks.

```
type ConnectedSocketsContainerType struct {
    M sync.Mutex
    ConnectedSockets map[string]*websocket.Conn
}

var ConnectedSocketsContainer = ConnectedSocketsContainerType{ M:sync.Mutex{} , ConnectedSockets: make(map[string]*websocket.Conn) }
```

In another package in GET request handler calls that method:

```
func send(socketID string,message string)  {
    sockethub.ConnectedSocketsContainer.M.Lock()
    sendToAll(message)
    sockethub.ConnectedSocketsContainer.M.Unlock()
}
func sendToAll(message string)  {
    for k := range sockethub.SocketsIDs {
        k.WriteMessage(1, []byte(message))
    }
}
```

The error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x10 pc=0x14d27f8]

goroutine 6 [running]:
github.com/fasthttp/websocket.(*Conn).WriteMessage(0xc00006aa78, 0xc00045e115, {0xc0004540f0, 0x29, 0xc00006ab2f})
        /Users/emre/go/pkg/mod/github.com/fasthttp/websocket@v1.4.3-rc.10/conn.go:753 +0x38
goserver/controllers/api.sendToAll({0xc00045e115, 0x29})
        /Users/emre/Documents/Free/SocketServer/goServer/controllers/api/socket.go:11 +0xac
goserver/controllers/api.send({0xc000456000, 0x15edfe1}, {0xc00045e115, 0x0})
        /Users/emre/Documents/Free/SocketServer/goServer/controllers/api/socket.go:22 +0x65
goserver/controllers/api.SendMessageController(0xc000128a50)
        /Users/emre/Documents/Free/SocketServer/goServer/controllers/api/socket.go:29 +0x71
github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2.(*App).next(0xc00019cb60, 0xc000456000)
        /Users/emre/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2@v2.23.0/router.go:127 +0x1d8
github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2.(*App).handler(0xc00019cb60, 0x10bb517)
        /Users/emre/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2@v2.23.0/router.go:155 +0xe5
github.com/valyala/fasthttp.(*Server).serveConn(0xc000126000, {0x16c4fa0, 0xc0000106e8})
        /Users/emre/go/pkg/mod/github.com/valyala/fasthttp@v1.31.0/server.go:2278 +0x122d
github.com/valyala/fasthttp.(*workerPool).workerFunc(0xc00014c000, 0xc00022dba0)
        /Users/emre/go/pkg/mod/github.com/valyala/fasthttp@v1.31.0/workerpool.go:223 +0xa9
github.com/valyala/fasthttp.(*workerPool).getCh.func1()
        /Users/emre/go/pkg/mod/github.com/valyala/fasthttp@v1.31.0/workerpool.go:195 +0x38
created by github.com/valyala/fasthttp.(*workerPool).getCh
        /Users/emre/go/pkg/mod/github.com/valyala/fasthttp@v1.31.0/workerpool.go:194 +0x1b5
exit status 2
```

Full example for go server. Please see two comments that specify working and not working code blocks.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
    "github.com/gofiber/websocket/v2"
)

func main() {

    app := fiber.New()

    ListenSocket(app)
    app.Get("/socket/send", SendMessageController )
    app.Listen(":3000")

}
const websocketHeaderKey = "Sec-Websocket-Key"

var ConnectedIDSockets sync.Map 

func SendMessageController( c *fiber.Ctx ) error {
    ConnectedIDSockets.Range(func(key, value interface{}) bool {
        c := value.(*websocket.Conn)
        
        if c == nil {
            // that line is not printed, c is not nil.
            fmt.Println("c is nil.")
            return true
        }

        // we have crash at that line, even we read the err.
        err := c.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte("message"))

        // program does not runs to here since it crashed.
        println("err:", err)
        return true
    })
    return nil
}

func ListenSocket(app *fiber.App) {
    app.Use("/ws", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        if websocket.IsWebSocketUpgrade(c) {
            c.Locals("allowed", true)
            c.Locals(websocketHeaderKey, string(c.Request().Header.Peek(websocketHeaderKey)))
            return c.Next()
        }
        return fiber.ErrUpgradeRequired
    })

    app.Get("/ws/:projectKEY", websocket.New(func(c *websocket.Conn) {

        socketID := c.Locals(websocketHeaderKey).(string)

        ConnectedIDSockets.Store(socketID, c)

        // that works.
        conn, _ := ConnectedIDSockets.Load(socketID)
        socketmap := conn.(*websocket.Conn)
        socketmap.WriteMessage(1, []byte(socketID))

    }))
}
```

Comment: which library does `WriteMessage` come from?  Find that doc and make sure you're calling it right.  For that matter, why are you even using fasthttp?  Their readme starts with, "For most cases net/http is much better as it's easier to use and can handle more cases".

Comment: I am using fiber, which I mentioned in tags. I also updated the question, please see the new info. No problem while using the variable inside the same package, the problem occurs when using from another route handler.

Comment: maps in go can cause data races, see https://dave.cheney.net/2015/12/07/are-go-maps-sensitive-to-data-races

Comment: You can try with `sync.Map`

Comment: Does the race detector detect any issues in your program? `go run -race .`

Comment: @rustyx I run the code with your command but it crashed when I requested to the backend. No data race warning.   objc[24140]: Attempt to use unknown class 0x7ff84b669500.
SIGABRT: abort

Comment: @Wolfgang your suggestion makes sense but it didn't work. Same result.

Comment: So, it didn't crash when sending the messages but when requesting to the backend? Share a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and we can look into it.

Comment: It crashed when sending the message. I can create the example but we also need a client to connect to a socket which the client is written in dart. Should I also create an example or that? That may be a little long.

Comment: The `*websocket.Conn` is likely always nil. As of Go 1.17, function parameters printed in the stack trace may no longer be accurate due to the new register based calling convention, so the stack trace in this case is misleading.
"A caveat is that the value of an argument that only lives in a register and is not stored to memory may be inaccurate." from https://go.dev/doc/go1.17

Comment: @1lann hi, thanks for the info. I also put if blocks inside the lib(WriteMessage method, helper method) and checked like that, if conn == nil blocks work in the helper method. I didn't understand the '*websocket.Conn is likely always nil' part, it is implemented in that way?

Comment: @EmreSURK You're saying even if you put `if k != nil { k.WriteMessage(...) }` inside the for loop in `sendToAll` the panic still happens? Are you sure your code is recompiling?

Comment: Yes, still happens, k is not nil. I updated the minimal reproducible example and took some notes, please can check them. The panic happens inside the lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This panic is confusing because there are actually two packages called `websocket`. One in `github.com/gofiber/websocket/v2` and another one in `github.com/fasthttp/websocket`, and both have their own `*websocket.Conn`. However the `websocket.Conn` in `github.com/gofiber/websocket` actually embeds the `websocket.Conn` from `github.com/fasthttp/websocket` (I know, terrible design) making what's going on unclear.

Your call to `c.WriteMessage` is actually going to `c.Conn.WriteMessage`, and `c.Conn` is what's nil. So in your nil check, you actually need to do `if c == nil || c.Conn == nil {` to check the embedded struct as well.

Comment: I see, that is right, c.Conn is nil. Any idea why c.Conn is nil and how to avoid?

Comment: You are right. I moved from fiber framework to gin framework and everything works fine.

Comment: @EmreSURK Sorry for the late answer but it's becuase you're not gracefully handling closed connections. (admittedly, Fiber is not handling them gracefully either, it shouldn't be setting it as nil ever, rather calls to `WriteMessage` should fail). But yes in general I never recommend Fiber, it's a bad library that is not Go idiomatic, not `net/http` compatible, and will only give you headaches down the line because of it.